# Почему интерпретатор javascript не передаёт значение переменной?

Tags: javascript, ооп, классы, функции

```
function createShape(shapeClass, x, y) {

    // интерпретатор ругается, что shapeClass - не является конструктором! (то есть он воспринимает это не как переменную, а как имя класса!) Как исправить? (в console.log выводятся значения, всё ОК!)

    var shape = new shapeClass(x, y, currentSize);

    // ... код...

    return shape;

}
```

---

Пример вызова:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    var shape = e.target.dataset.shape; 
    if (shape && shapeMap.hasOwnProperty(shape)) { // передаём Класс из карты соответствий 
        var shape = createShape(shapeMap[shape]);
        app.setCurrentShape(shape); 
    }
});
```

---

```
// карта соответствий 
const shapeMap = { 
    circle: 'Circle', 
    quad: 'Quad', 
    triangle: 'Triangle' 
};
```

Comment: Покажи как именно ты вызываешь `createShape`

Comment: А что вы передаете в аргументе `shapeClass`?

Comment: document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            var shape = e.target.dataset.shape;

            if (shape && shapeMap.hasOwnProperty(shape)) {
                // передаём Класс из карты соответствий
                var shape = createShape(shapeMap[shape]);
                app.setCurrentShape(shape);
            }
        });

Comment: передаю название класса

Comment: @AlexeyZolotov ну так название класса это не класс, а строка

Comment: @AlexeyZolotov, а нужно передать не название, а сам класс

Comment: Так как поменять, чтобы заработало то?)

Comment: @AlexeyZolotov, покажи что у тебя в `shapeMap`

Comment: // карта соответствий
        const shapeMap = {
            circle: 'Circle',
            quad: 'Quad',
            triangle: 'Triangle'
        };

Comment: @AlexeyZolotov, попробуй кавычки убрать

Comment: сработало) супер, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В объекте `shapeMap` хранятся *строки*.

Строки – это объекты, а объекты не могут использоваться в качестве конструктора.

Для решения можно хранить в словаре не имена, а сами классы:

```
const shapeMap = { 
    circle: Circle, 
    quad: Quad, 
    triangle: Triangle 
};
```

Comment: Хмм, если путаться - то уж основательно. Если строки у тебя считаются объектами, хотя они примитивы, то конструкторы - тоже объекты (хотя они функции). получается, что конструкторы не могут использоваться в качестве конструктора. Что-то тут не так..

Comment: Кстати `instanceof` говорит, что конструктор - объект, а строка - нет)